# Android Layout Best option for attached layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

[image: Layout image]

I want to make a similar layout in Android with two additional button in bottom right and left corner. I'm new to android development GUI. Is grid layout the best option to achieve this or I should use any other layout.

Comment: Show what you have tried first.

Answer (score -1):

I would not suggest using GridLayout. If you can, try to use Constraints layout, if that is not an option, use combination of RelativeLayout and LinearLayout where needed.

There is no 100% correct answer, try multiple ways and you will find one that suits you the best.